# What is the order of candidates in 2014 moderator election?

Tags: support, moderator-elections

Within the election process a set of candidates is presented to vote for:

[SuperUser candidates tab](https://superuser.com/election/3?tab=election).

What is the order choosen to present all the candidates?

Comment: It's random so there is no order

Comment: Quoting the blue box to the right on the linked page: *All candidates are displayed in random order.*

Comment: Thank you for bringing my attention to this information.
This information is there and using a color to maintain it as a side information.
Please feel free to remove my low grade question.

Comment: This question definitely has merit as long as the election is ongoing.

Answer (score 3):

Candidates are displayed in random order, as mentioned in the informational side bar on the election page:

[image]